# Помогите разобраться в коде PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите что означает каждая строка этого кода:

```js
$text = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$ar = array('/\м..+/si','/\ж..+/si');
$new_text = "";
 
$array_text = explode("\r\n",$text); 
foreach($array_text as $value) {
    $new_text .= preg_replace($ar,"",$value);
}
echo str_replace(",","",$new_text);
```

Comment: 1. `file_get_contents` — Читает содержимое файла в строку; 2. `$ar` - массив с регулярными выражениями. 3. `$new_text` - объявление пустой строки. 4. 'explode` — Разбивает строку с помощью разделителя. 5. Для разбитых частей цикл. 6. В цикле заменяем значения, которые нашли с помощью регулярных выражений из массива и в свою очередь записываем их в новую строку. И последнее - выводим.

Comment: @Николай Василенков каковы ваши предположения по поводу данного кода?

Comment: Только то что первая строка получает файл text, а последняя выводит результат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = "каждый охотник\r\nжелает знать\r\n, где сидит фазан";
// эквивалент $text = file_get_contents('text.txt');, для примера
// \r\n - конец и перенос строки

$ar = array('/\м..+/si','/\ж..+/si');
// массив регулярных выражений

$new_text = "";

$array_text = explode("\r\n",$text);
//Array(
//    [0] => каждый охотник
//    [1] => желает знать
//    [2] => , где сидит фазан
// )

foreach($array_text as $value) {
    $new_text .= preg_replace($ar, "", $value);
    // замена по регулярному выражению
}

echo str_replace(",", "", $new_text);
// ка где сидит фазан
```

[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php)

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

[Регулярные выражения для новичков и не только](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbgvaQ_rM4I)